# How to use entry and lookup function in the same program to display the string corresponding to the numbers

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When I enter 4 at the runtime, the following program should return me the string "four" and similarly the string`s corresponding to 5, 6, 7 and 8.

This should be done using `entry` function.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE x AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "9"  LABEL "Enter a digit between 4 and 8".
DEFINE VARIABLE show AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(5)" EXTENT 5   LABEL "Literal" INITIAL ["four","five","six","seven","eight"].
DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER.

REPEAT:  
  SET x AUTO-RETURN.  

  i = LOOKUP(x, "4,5,6,7,8",",")  . 
  IF i = 0 THEN
  DO:    
    MESSAGE "Digit must be 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8. Try again.".   
    UNDO, RETRY.  
  END. 

  MESSAGE ENTRY(i, show[i], ",") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

a) Your LOOKUP function was wrong. First argument is x (the expression to locate in the list), then the list as a comma-delimited string
b) No need for an ELSE. As the UNDO, RETRY stops the current iteration of the loop
c) Since show is an ARRAY, just referent the array-element.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE x AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "9"  LABEL "Enter a digit between 4 and 8".
DEFINE VARIABLE show AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(5)" EXTENT 5   LABEL "Literal" INITIAL ["four","five","six","seven","eight"].
define variable i as integer .

REPEAT:  
SET x AUTO-RETURN.  

i = lookup(x, "4,5,6,7,8",",")  . 
IF i = 0 
THEN
DO:    
MESSAGE "Digit must be 4,5,6,7, or 8. Try again.".   
UNDO, RETRY.  
END. 

MESSAGE show[i]
VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

END.
```

Comment: ya i agree with you , but this program has to done using ENTRY function

Comment: i have edited the above program posted by me,it displays  results for only 1st entry and  for the rest it is throwing error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decide if you want to use `ENTRY` or an array. Mixing makes no sence in this case!

```
DEFINE VARIABLE x    AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "9"    LABEL "Enter a digit between 4 and 8".
DEFINE VARIABLE show AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT "x(5)" LABEL "Literal" INITIAL "four,five,six,seven,eight".
DEFINE VARIABLE i    AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

REPEAT:  
    SET x AUTO-RETURN.  

    i = LOOKUP(x, "4,5,6,7,8", ",")  NO-ERROR. 
    IF i = 0 THEN DO:    
        MESSAGE "Digit must be 4,5,6,7, or 8. Try again.".   
        UNDO, RETRY.  
    END. 

    MESSAGE entry(i, show, ",") VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.

END.
```